pronunciation of костьми
Is it possible to voice the ст in костьми, e.g. in the phrase лечь костьми. Can you pronounce it лечь кaздьми?
All the examples I have of this phrase show no medial voicing (my examples are from forvo), but retroactive voicing is the norm in Russian (как дела: каг дела; лишь бы: лиж бы; моих друзей: моиɣ друзей; с глаз долой: з глаз долой).
Is the м a less likely candidate for medial retroactive voicing? Or is there some other reason why костьми isn't usually каздьми?


Is the м a less likely candidate for medial retroactive voicing?

Is it ever? I don't think so. Смог, этот мяч, астма... no voicing.

Voicing occurs only before voiced obstruent consonants (б, г, д, ж, з). It does not occur before sonorants (л, м, н, р). (It also does not occur before в, unless it is followed by an obstruent consonant.)
Reference: "Russian voicing assimilation, final devoicing, and the problem of [v] (or, The mouse that squeaked)", Jaye Padgett - University of California, Santa Cruz
